# Андроид проект не видит изменений в андроид библиотеке (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Есть андроид либа, есть андроид проект. Либа подключена к проекту.

Как-то коряво работает рефакторинг.
Беру, в либе переименовываю метод. Всё отрабатывает. Переименовывается и в либе и в проекте.

Теперь делаю Move. Перемещаю метод из одного класса в другой (всё в либе). Или переменовываю класс в либе. Меняется только в либе. То есть остаётся только руками менять.

Или пишу новый метод в либе. Проект его не видит, пока не нажму F5 в проекте.

Но это никуда не годится. Есть какое-то решение, кроме перехода на Android Studio (он и так будет, но позже).

Comment: К сожалению Android и Eclipse дело тёмное, поэтому чем скорее перейдёте, тем лучше, в чём проблема перейти сейчас не знаю, но могу сказать, что Android Studio хорошо пережевывает проекты с Eclipse, поэтому не нужно бояться, что что-то не так пойдёт

Comment: Обычно в эклипсе постоянно нужно заново билдить проекты, т.е. чистите их (Clean), а потом выполняете Build

Comment: Единственным явным плюсом Eclipse в сравнении с Android Studio, по моему личному мнению, является адекватная поддержка JNI

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, я в группе, решаю, когда перейти не я (но тут скорее проблема со временем).

Comment: Но мне что-то подсказывает, глюки (неожиданно вылезающие) будут и в Android Studio :-)

Comment: Поверьте, их там НАМНОГО меньше и целая КУЧА плюшек полезных. Что же по поводу того, что не вы решаете, то можете как минимум объяснить людям, или конкретно тому, кто решает всю полезность и безболезненность перехода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было найдено ожидаемое решение: AndroidStudio. Отдельное спасибо ребятам из jetbrains.